# Android SmsManager adding country code to sms while Intent to launch SMS apps do not

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

For some odd reason, when trying to send to some shortcodes (e.g. 21588518) from my country via the SmsManager APIs, the country code is prepended to the shortcode (e.g. +6321588518).
However, when using an intent to send the SMS via Google Messenger, the destination address is not manipulated.
Is Google Messenger probably not using the SmsManager APIs? Or should I be doing any encoding beforehand?
Thanks!

Comment: you can perhaps use this SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
  smsManager.sendTextMessage("<PHONE_NUMBER>", null, "<MESSAGE_BODY>", null, null);

Comment: @VaibhavBarad that's what I've been using

Comment: I tried it at my end but i did now get. But the message was sent to the no. I specufied and no country code was attached by default.